# How to work around missing insertId in WebSQL

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-8, web-sql

I want to obtain the ID of the just inserted record into a WebSQL database. WebSQL has the InsertID Property for this task.

However this property is not supported in the Cordova WebSQL Plugin.

- The Cordova WebSQL Plugin adds WebSQL to Windows8 Cordova Apps
- https://github.com/msopentech/cordova-plugin-websql/
- This plugin however doesn't support the insertId Property - see quirks section

How to efficiently obtain the ID of a newly inserted record without using the insertId?

Comment: How are you creating the insertID for the row? Is it autoincrement? or generating a sequence?

Comment: currently autoincrement - the database creates the id. currently I don't save the last added id. I could create a sequence in the worst case, though I don't know how to make sure that it's unique

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a workaround for **SQLITE** db and assuming that the implementation of **WebSQL** is similar to SQLLite db.
I feel that you would at least have to make two passes (two SQL) statements for getting the last insert ID. The easiest option is trying to get the maximum id that has been inserted in the table e.g if id is the column set to autoincrement then use the below sql.

```
select max(id) from table
```

and then using the **max(id)+1** from above as the insertId that would get inserted into the table.
2nd Option:
In SQLite when you create a table with an autoincrement column an entry is made in the **sqlite_sequence** table. It holds the value of the last id that has been applied to the column. You need to select the id for the table as shown below.
You need to find out what is a similar table **WebSQL.**

```
select seq from sqlite_sequence where table = <table_name>
```

Increment the **seq** from above query to 1 to get the sequence that will be used by the autoincrement for the desired table as the last **insertId**.